# how to autobuild an associated polymorphic activerecord object in rails 3

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class ItemSource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, :polymorphic => true
end

class RandomProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :item_source, :as => :product, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

What I'd like to do is is call:

```
a = RandomProduct.find(1)
a.item_source
```

and if item_source doesn't already exist (= nil), then build it automatically (build_item_source).

previously, I did this with alias_chain_method, but that's not supported in Rails 3.
oh, and I also tried this to no avail:

```
class RandomProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :item_source, :as => :product, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy

  module AutoBuildItemSource
    def item_source
      super || build_item_source
    end
  end  
  include AutoBuildItemSource
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Rails 3, `alias_method_chain` (and `alias_method`, and `alias`) work fine:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :inverse_of => :user

  # This works:
  # 
  #   def profile_with_build
  #     profile_without_build || build_profile
  #   end
  #   alias_method_chain :profile, :build
  #
  # But so does this:

  alias profile_without_build profile
  def profile
    profile_without_build || build_profile
  end
end
```

But there's always `accept_nested_attributes_for` as an alternative, which calls build when `profile_attributes` are set. Combine it with `delegate` (optional) and you won't have to worry if the record exists or not:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :inverse_of => :user
  delegate :website, :to => :profile, :allow_nil => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

User.new.profile # => nil
User.new.website # => nil
u = User.new :profile_attributes => { :website => "http://example.com" }
u.profile # => #<Profile id: nil, user_id: nil, website: "http://example.com"...>
```

If the association is always created, delegation isn't necessary (but may be helpful, anyhow).

(Note: I set `:inverse_of` to make `Profile.validates_presence_of :user` work and to generally save queries.)

Answer (score 3):

(Rails 4, FYI)

I personally prefer setting it up with `after_initialize`

```
after_initialize :after_initialize

def after_initialize
  build_item_source if item_source.nil?
end
```

This also works well because you can automatically use forms with what would otherwise be an empty association (HAML because it's nicer):

```
= form_for @product do |f|
  = f.fields_for :item_source do |isf|
    = isf.label :prop1
    = isf.text_field :prop1
```

If you didn't have the item_source built already, the label and text field wouldn't render at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating the `item_source` when the `RandomProduct` is created:

```
class RandomProduct << ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_item_source
end
```

Of course, if you need to pass specific arguments to the item source, you could do something like this, instead:

```
class RandomProduct << ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :set_up_item_source

  protected
    def set_up_item_source
      create_item_source(
        :my => "options",
        :go => "here"
      )
    end
end
```

Comment: I ended up doing a creation on before validation (b/c i have to ensure it creates the item source at the time the product is created), but the solution you proposed is basically the same thing. Thanks for validating it.

Answer (score 0):

Not that you really need a gem for this since it's so simple to do yourself, but here's a gem that makes it even easier to declare an auto-build:

https://github.com/TylerRick/active_record_auto_build_associations